# Interval functions

Tags: functions

I'm kinda a greenhorn in maths and young and unexperienced, but one thought popped in my head that google couldn't satisfy.

Let $g(x) = \sin(x)$.

Then wouldn't be  $g([a,b]) = \{ (x, y): a \leq x \leq b \; \text{and} \; y = g(x)  \}$ pretty fine?

Is $g([a,b])$ meaningless or incorrect? If it's not, what would be the result? Is there a function that argument is an interval? Or this whole idea is based on my incorrect vision of maths skewed by programming?

I'm sorry for unskilful use of MathJax and maths at all, it's just pure curiosity.

Comment: The notation used in general is $g([a,b])$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm fixing it now.

Comment: and $g([a,b])=\{g(x): x\in [a,b]\}$ I find the easiest expression to understand what does $g([a,b])$ means

Comment: I meant like a set of pairs $(x,y)$ where $x$ is an every value from range $[a,b]$ and $y$ is a corresponding $y = g(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $$ \{ (x, y): a \leq x \leq b \; \text{and} \; y = g(x)  \}$$
is commonly called the [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function) of the function $g(x)$ on the interval $[a,b]$.

It is common to use the notation $g(S)$, for set $S$, to mean the set of all values $g(x)$ takes on over the set $S$, i.e. $$\{g(x):x\in S\}$$

Comment: Absolutely, $[a,b]=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : a \leq x \leq b\}$ in set notation.